# StackBlitz and PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, stackblitz

I am putting a demo for a client using StackBlitz

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhrvww?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

The error being shown is

```
Error in /turbo_modules/primeng@14.1.2/fesm2015/primeng-table.mjs (4051:169)
can't access lexical declaration 'ColumnFilter' before initialization
```

I am not using **ColumnFilter** anywhere in my code. How do I resolve it?

Comment: It seems like StackBlitz doesn't play well with latest version of PrimeNg. Have you try it on your local Angular with the same version?

Comment: That's a known issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11931

Comment: i downgraded my PrimeNg and same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your target in `tsconfig.json` from `es2015` to `es5`.

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this issue is related or not, but making this adjustment in your stackblitz seems to resolve the issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51801

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zylztz?file=tsconfig.json